# How to create a dictionary from two other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am facing a problem with dictionaries(python 3+).
I have uploaded two different txt files in two different dictionaries in python.
So, now I would like to combine some arguments from the dictionary1 with dictionary2 in order to build a new dictionary.

```
ratings: [ ["142", "196", 5] ]

title: { "196" : "Noisy", "233" : "The Sunshine" }
```

and I would like to create a new dictionary with user IDs as keys (e.g., "142" (from ratings) and titles as values (retrieved by indexing into title, e.g., title["196"]).

My code is :

For the first one:

```
try:
    ratings = {}
    for line in open('u.ratings'):
        line = line.split('\t')[0:3]
        print(line)
except IOError as ioerr:
        print('File error: ' + str(ioerr))
print(ratings)
```

Second one:

```
try:
    movies = {}
    for line in open('u.movies'):
        (id, title) = line.split('|')[0:2]
        movies[id] = title

except IOError as ioerr:
    print('File error: ' + str(ioerr))
print(movies)
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: you mean in order to upload them?

Comment: OK, your posted code for the "review" part doesn't create a dictionary (or a list at the moment.)  Maybe do something like `ratings[id],  [ movie_id, rating ] = line.split('|')[0:2]`

Comment: Actually, doesn't plays this one. My result should be something like that:                             
{142: 196|
when 142 = key
and 196 = value

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will make a few assumptions:

User ID is a given, collected somehow, and in this case `user_id = 142`

Since you have the data already loaded, instead of creating a third dictionary, you can use the first dictionary to index into the second dictionary. (If you want a single data source, start taking a look at the `SQLite` database that Python ships with.)

```
user_id = 142

reviewed_title = title[ratings[user_id]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you right:

```
x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
y = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}

def two_dicts_in_one(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   
    z.update(y)    
    return z

z = two_dicts_in_one(x, y)

print(z)
```

output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

Comment: Or even `z = {**x, **y}`.

Comment: @rysson, it is a very beautiful solution

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand what you are trying to do.
If you want to **append** the ratings of a movie to a movies dictionary, and keep the userID of that rating I suggest you to try something like this

```
movies= {
"196":{"name":"Noisy","ratings":[]},
"233":{"name":"The Sunshine","ratings":[]}
}
ratings = [
 {"userID":"142","movieID":"196","num": 5},
 {"userID":"142","movieID":"233","num": 4},
 {"userID":"142","movieID":"196","num": 4.3},
]

for rating in ratings:
  movies[rating["movieID"]]["ratings"].append(rating)

print(movies)
```

The for loop fill a ratings array for each movie with objects which contains all the rating data.

Hope it helps.